# bootstrap v. 3.0 with octopress or jekyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll, octopress

I am experimenting with octopress and jekyll and want to implement twitters bootstrap in version 3.0. I found some themes for octopress that are based on bootstrap version 2.3. Now I am wondering how to use version 3.0 with octopress.

Is there a script to implement [sass bootstrap](http://alademann.github.io/sass-bootstrap/) or from the [original sources](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: Why not just use bootstrap 2.3? You may have to do a significant amount of work to get the themes to work in bootstrap 3.0, and you'd gain very little by doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about it as well, but 3.0 is a mobile first theme where as 2.3 is not. But anyways after playing around with jekyll for a while, I figured I'll stay with WP for a while longer.

Comment: Please [take a look](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/wiki/3rd-Party-Octopress-Themes) and play with.